# Is it possible to define generic index in elastic search using nest?

Tags: c#, generics, elasticsearch

How can i generate index of generic type.This is my code to insert document into generic index which is defined by .I get error in the **Tres emp** section saying "Tres is a type, which is not valid in the given context"

```
 public void InsertDocument<Tres>(ElasticClient es, Tres emp,IndexName name) where Tres: new()
    {
        es.Index<Tres>(**Tres emp**, x => x.Index(name).Type("logs")); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a reference for generic "Tres" type. To perform functionality of generic type as you expected you should create a base class which other elasticsearch index classes derived from it. So, you can pass the custom elasticsearch index classes in that way.

Firstly, create a base class for Elasticsearch index classes.

```
public class EsIndicesBaseClass
{

}
```

And I provided a sample Elasticsearch index model;

```
public class EsSampleIndexModel : EsIndicesBaseClass
{ 
    public string SampleProperty{get;set;}
}
```

And change your generic method to

```
public void InsertDocument<Tres>(ElasticClient es, Tres emp,IndexName name) where Tres: EsIndicesBaseClass
    {
        es.Index<Tres>(emp, x => x.Index(name).Type("logs")); 
    }
```

Usage;

```
var esSampleIndexData = new EsSampleIndexModel();

InsertDocument<EsSampleIndexModel>(es, esSampleIndexData , name);
```

Comment: worked when i added a base class.Why do we need base class?

Comment: I provide some explanation in the answer.